# Why do I need context root for spring boot restful api?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

When building restful api in spring boot, we can configure the contextRoot path, for example:

```
http://customer-api:8080/customer-api/
```

why do I need a context root? can I just use:

```
http://customer-api:8080/
```

Just want to understand.

Comment: Of course you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a context root. The Spring Boot default for `server.context-path` is `/`. You only need a context root if you are deploying an application under a domain that hosts multiple applications under separate context roots. That's a fairly common scenario, though.